Ergodicity breaking in the Ising model
Let's consider the Ising model in dimension $d \geq 2$ with constant coupling $J= 1$ between direct neighbors and without external field.
It is common to read in physics texts that, under the critical temperature, the symmetry of the problem (w.r.t. magnetization inversion) and its ergodicity are broken.
For instance in this article:

Ergodicity is globally broken because the trajectory remains confined within the same component in which it has
originated, but continues to hold separately within each component.

However, physicists usually don't give a precise mathematical definition of ergodicity breaking and no proof of this fact.
I suppose that a mathematical definition of ergodicity breaking in this case could be that, given an initial configuration with all spins up and hence global magnetization $M \gt 0$, the time $T$ for reaching a configuration with $M \lt 0$  has an infinite expectation:
$\mathbb{E}[T] = +\infty$.
That would, however, suppose that a dynamic is given for the time evolution of the spins, which usually isn't the case (physicists are generally interested in the Boltzmann statistics for the configurations when studying the Ising model, not its dynamic).
My question is: what mathematical definition of ergodicity breaking should we consider in this case and how to prove it?

A good start could be the references given in this WP article about Spin glass, in particular the Sherrington Kirkpatrick model. I am not an expert at all. Try asking on PSE. Most modern physicists are keen to give precise mathematical definitions when asked.

Ergodicity breaking (like phase transition) only applies in thermodynamic limit. Typically, if you try to simulate the Ising model using a Monte Carlo Markov chain method, the process will be ergodic since you can only have a finite number of spins. The idea is that as the number of spins $N$ increases, the dynamic exhibits separation of time scales, which is the regime of interest for physical applications.
When the system stays ergodic, you would expect that the relaxation time of the process converges to a finite value as $N\to\infty$. Thus the characteristic time scales of most macroscopic processes (mean first passage time etc.) scale similarly and differ by numerical prefactors. In the Ising model, this is what you would get in the paramagnetic (disordered) phase.
In contrast, in the ferromagnetic (ordered) phase, the time $\tau$ to jump from one to the other follows an Arrhenius law:
$$
\tau\asymp e^{-\beta\Delta F}
$$
with $\Delta F$ the height of the fee energy barrier between the two states. Since it is extensive, $\Delta F\sim N$ so the time scales exponentially. Within a magnetised state though, you still have an $N^0$ relaxation time, hence the large separation of time scales. Therefore, if you are interested in timescales of order $N^0$, in the thermodynamic limit, your system only equilibrates in one of the two states, ignoring the other. This is precisely ergodicity breaking.
Ergodicity breaking, while being a dynamic notion, has its influence even in equilibrium statistics (with no dynamics). Following the Dobrushin–Lanford–Ruelle (DLR), there are many different Gibbs states satisfying the DLR equation. You can find more details of the formalism in Statistical Mechanics of Lattice Systems by Velenik or Thermodynamic Formalism by Ruelle (very dense). This plurality of solutions comes from the thermodynamic limit as well, as the usual Boltzmann distribution is in some sense insufficient to define uniquely the distribution.
